# No sound from headphones Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

So I had this problem from the day I installed ubuntu on the separate partition. I get sound from my laptop, but nothing from the headphones, I would usually restart my laptop 2-3 times and it would go back to normal for a week or so, but this time after 10 restarts, it is not solving the issue. I am aware that this is a Ubuntu 16.04 bug, but did someone find a solution for this? This is what I done/investigated so far:

`pavucontrol` shows that my headphones are detecting sound if I play a video from youtube, but I get no sound.

Overall sound settings show that they detect my headphones.

I also ran update and dist-upgrade, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :
In **Pavucontrol**, "**output device**" tab:
when headphones are  connected , you logically  see "headphones" in output port:
  but try to switch port to "speakers"   .

This worked  recently for me on a HP 820 g1.
Real fix  is to use **hdajackretask** to modify bad  audio feed to  headphone,  but it depends on your hardware .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I simply restart (kill) the sound daemon that I am using on my laptop (*Lenovo ideapad 100* on **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**).

In the terminal, I run this:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why, but on my laptop I can use the regular headphone jack on a fresh boot.

But after a suspend I need to move my headphones to the Line Out jack.  If I use the headphone jack I don't get any sound.  When I try to play a sound I can see the Output Device volume meter moving but don't hear anything.

If I unplug the speakers kick on, as expected.  Plug back in and nothing.  But if I move the headphones to the other jack it works.

I don't know what the icon is supposed to mean, but it looks like a squared off sine wave with an arrow aiming out which is why I called it Line Out.

That might help somebody.

EDIT: I figured out that it's the S/PDIF Out Jack that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my 2 laptops with latest Ubuntu 16.04.

**The next steps helped me**:

1. Power Off your laptop.
2. Unplug Headphones from the jack.
3. Power On your laptop.
4. Only after the Login procedure, plug in your headphones.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to update the linux kernel inside ubuntu 16.04.
I once clicked on install updates which did modifications to the operating system
and also updated the kernel to a newer version, that was also the reason why
my headphones didn't work, speaker audio was fine tough.
After I followed this guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus

about how to update the linux kernel to the very newest available version and rebooted once
the headphones work fine again.

I used this command:
apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04